# In the SilverStripe backend, is there a way to render a column with a template?

Tags: silverstripe

I have defined $summary_fields in my data object and I want to render one column ("Tags") as a list of chips (al la Material UI), but I want to avoid adding any HTML to my data object class. I was hoping that I could simply do something like (simplified for brevity):

```
$template = new Template('my_column_template_name');
return $template->render($this->Tags());
```

Is this, or something similar, possible in SilverStripe?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be quite simple:

```
$this->owner->renderWith('Admin/Models/Member/tags-column');
```